# Separating one file in two using timestamp

Tags: r, file

Having a txt file in the following format:

```
 2011-01-01 00:00:00 text text text text
 2011-01-01 00:01:00 text text text text
 text
 2011-01-01 00:02:00 text text text text
 ....
 ....
 ....
 ....
 2011-01-02 00:00:00 text text text text
 2011-01-02 00:01:00 text text text text
```

All file contains data of two calendar days.
Is it possible to separate the file into two different files, one for everyday?

Comment: Do you want the data in R? Or do you just want the file split?

Comment: Split them and save them into 2 different txt files

Comment: Are the files sorted? And is there a heading that needs to be copied to both files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dat <- readLines(textConnection(" 2011-01-01 00:00:00 text text text text
  2011-01-01 00:01:00 text text text text  text
  2011-01-01 00:02:00 text text text text
  2011-01-02 00:00:00 text text text text
  2011-01-02 00:01:00 text text text text"))

grouped.lines <- split(dat, substr(dat, 1,11) )
grouped.lines
$` 2011-01-01`
[1] " 2011-01-01 00:00:00 text text text text"      
[2] " 2011-01-01 00:01:00 text text text text  text"
[3] " 2011-01-01 00:02:00 text text text text"      

$` 2011-01-02`
[1] " 2011-01-02 00:00:00 text text text text"
[2] " 2011-01-02 00:01:00 text text text text"
```

It's more efficient to process these as separate items in a single list. It will create problems if you split them into separate objects. They can be accessed by text names or by numeric reference. (But do note that the leading space would need to be in the name if a leading space was in your text file.)

Answer (score 2):

read data in with read.table()

we should have a data.frame similar to :

```
df <- data.frame(d = c("2011-01-01 00:00:00", "2011-01-01 00:01:00"), x = 0:1)
```

apply split()

```
dfl <- split(df, df$d)
```

Map write.table to split

```
Map(write.table, dfl, file = paste(names(dfl), "txt", sep = "."), row.names = FALSE, sep = ";")
```

Comment: Please note that it seems like OP wish to split by date, not date-time.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to read all the lines of the file.

you can try to do so using

```
library(package=reshape)
```

then the function `read.table` might help

then you will have to compare all lines and write them back in two new files

Comment: This is a comment/suggestion, not an answer.